# Difference between using media or width directly in source tag

Tags: html, css

How do these two examples of sources inside `<picture>` tag

```
<source srcset="img-256.jpg 256w,
                img-512.jpg 512w"></source>
```

and

```
<source srcset="img-256.jpg" media="(min-width: 256px)"></source>
<source srcset="img-512.jpg" media="(min-width: 512px)"></source>
```

differ in terms of browser behaviour? Are both of them interchangable?

Comment: Basically they're just different ways of achieving the same thing. [<source>: The Media or Image Source element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#:~:text=The%20HTML%20element%20specifies,not%20have%20a%20closing%20tag.)

Comment: I can't find any documentation about firs version, and Validator has many complains for both https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/